# Converting Date to Calendar issues

Tags: java, date, calendar

Today is 2013-02-25, but why this code returns 2013-03-25?

```
       String currentDate =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd hh mm ss").format(new java.util.Date());
       System.out.println("current Date "+currentDate);
       StringTokenizer  token = new StringTokenizer(currentDate);
       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       cal.set(Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken()),
               Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken()), 
               Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken()), 
               Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken()),
               Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken()),
               Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken()));
       String calenderDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(cal.getTime());
       System.out.println("calender date "+calenderDate);
       cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1); //  set to one month ago
       String pastDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(cal.getTime());
       System.out.println("past Date "+pastDate);
```

> out put
>
> current Date 2013 02 25 04 56 26
>
> calender date 2013-03-25 04:56:26
>
> past Date 2013-02-25 04:56:26

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subtract one to the month. So it works the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29). I.e.:

> month - the value used to set the MONTH calendar field. Month value is 0-based. e.g., 0 for January.

Comment: look at the Calender date not past date, even the past date is not correct, I have subtracted one month but it still 2013-02-25.

Comment: in the set method do `Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken()) - 1` where you pass the month. As everyone said, the Calendar is 0 indexed for month. So for january it expects 0 not 1 and so on.

Answer (score 3):

In the JDK, month values start with `0`. So `2` = March.

From the [`Calendar#set` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29):

> `month` - the value used to set the `MONTH` calendar field. Month value is `0`-based. e.g., `0` for January.

Answer (score 3):

Calendar months start at 0, see JavaDoc:

> @param month the value used to set the `MONTH` calendar field.
>        * Month value is 0-based. e.g., 0 for January.

This is a royal PITA and most Java developers lost some time on that one, it certainly violates the principle of least surprise. Be very careful when using the Calendar class... There are alternatives like Joda time.